# Adding two outlets to a new basement kitchen. What is the Ontario electrical code requirement?

Tags: electrical

I'm building my basement and has a small kitchen (7 x 7 feet). I'm adding two outlets at above counter top level (counter top is not their yet). Should this be in a dedicated 20amp circuit or can it be part of another 15 amp circuit? What is the best and recommended practice?

Comment: Not an answer because (a) I don't know any Ontario specifics and (b) basement (not primary kitchen) may change things, but in general: Kitchen countertop receptacles must be on 20A circuits dedicated to that usage (and some limited exceptions). Plus **must** be GFCI protected (breaker or 1st receptacle in the chain).

Comment: Thanks and its correct. Also, now I need an AFCI.